# How to find and modify a TextBox in some word document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, office-interop

I have to access and change text of some text boxes of some word document by the TextBox id.
for example suppose that i have some object named txtDate in a word document and I want to change its content to now's date, so how can i get this object by its id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void SearchTextBox(Word.Document oDoc,string name,string newContent)
    {
        foreach (Word.Shape shape in oDoc.Shapes)
            if (shape.Name == name)
            {
                shape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Text = newContent;
                return;
            }
    }
```